# SQL Join for two scripts

Tags: join, sql-server-2000

I am trying to join two script

```
--script 1         
select  
    t.vendor_code,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [CLOSED_DATE]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([CLOSED_DATE]) as char(20)))) as [CLOSED_DATE],
    count(t.vendor_code) as [No_of_Case] 
from 
    dbo.FTX_FA_CASE t WITH (NOLOCK) 
where 
    [CLOSED_DATE] is not null 
group by  
    t.vendor_code, CLOSED_DATE
```

and

```
--script 2  
SELECT  
    (RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20)))) + ',') 
FROM 
    efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
WHERE 
    1 = 1 
    AND CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -5 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
    AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

which return data like this:

[image]

I want a single script which return this output:

[image]

Basically I am trying to get all the data of second table and no_of_Case from 1st table. The month which is not present in 1st script , for that no_of_case value should be "0".

Please advice !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
    name, 
    (select distinct date 
     from Table_1 t2 
     where t1.date = t2.date),
    count([no of count]) 
from
    Table_1 t1
group by 
    name, date
```